# Recursing Binary Decision Diagrams in SML

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, sml, smlnj

In one of my classes at university, we are learning functional programming through SML/NJ.

I have been given an assignment which requires us to perform a number of operations on Binary Decision Diagrams. (conjunction, disjunction, not, etc.)

Based on this truth table

[image: table]

I have the following function defined

```
fun IfThenElse(p,q,r) = 
  if p then q else r;
```

Then, we have the BDD (ROBDD) datatype declared as such

```
datatype ROBDD = true
               | false
               | IfThenElse of string * ROBDD * ROBDD;
```

So far this is all fairly straightforward. I'm getting lost on actually operating on BDD's, for instance, creating an ROBDD which represents the conjunction of two ROBDD's.

My function declaration so far looks like this

```
infix bddAnd;
fun op bddAnd(first:ROBDD,second:ROBDD) = 
   ...
```

It will be called with two ROBDD's, something like this

```
val conjunction = IfThenElse("p", true, false) bddAnd IfThenElse("q", true, false);
```

From here, I'm not really sure where to start. My professor has given us this hint:

> Of course, `True bddAnd anyROBDD` will be just `anyROBDD`. To get the ordering: If you’re asked to compute
>   `(IfThenElse(p, ϕ, ψ) bddAnd IfThenElse(q, χ, θ))`
>   the proposition letter at the root of the resultant ROBDD will be either p or q – whichever is less. So you’ll need
>   3 cases: `p < q`, `p = q`, and `p > q`. Having determined the root, you recurse down the branches

The first part makes sense, but I'm left with two questions.

**1. How do I determine the root of any ROBDD?**

If it's just `true` or `false`, it doesn't have one, right? So there should be a special case for just being given a boolean? If we are given a more fleshed out ROBDD, like `IfThenElse("p", true, false)`, how do I gain access to `p`, in the ROBDD structure? Note that the first argument of an `IfThenElse` will always be a letter.

**2. How do I recurse through the ROBDD's?**

I understand the basics of recursive functions in SML, but I'm confused on how to do it within the ROBDD structure, compared to say, lists. I'm guessing I need to build some sort of curried functions that operate on each argument in the ROBDD, but I'm really not sure how to structure it.

Apologies for the long winded question, but I'm really having a hard time understanding how to operate on the ROBDD structure. Any explanation would be very helpful, thank you!

EDIT:

After some syntax and renaming, my `bddAnd` function now looks like this

```
infix bddAnd;
fun op bddAnd (true, second) = second
  | op bddAnd (first, true) = first
  | op bddAnd (false, _) = false
  | op bddAnd (_, false) = false
  | op bddAnd ((left as (IfThenElse (prop1, true1, else1))), (right as (IfThenElse (prop2, true2, else2)))) = 
        if prop1 < prop2 then 
          IfThenElse (prop1, true1 bddAnd right, else1 bddAnd right)
        else if prop1 > prop2 then
          IfThenElse (prop2, true2 bddAnd left, else2 bddAnd left)
        else
          IfThenElse (prop1, true1 bddAnd right, else1 bddAnd left);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching is usually a good starting point.

The cases involving `True` and `False` are simple:

```
fun op bddAnd (True, second) = second
     | bddAnd (first, True) = first
     | bddAnd (False, _) = False
     | bddAnd (_, False) = False
```

the last one is more interesting:

```
 | bddAnd (IfThenElse (v1, t1, e1)) (IfThenElse (v2, t2, e2)) = ... what? ...
```

As your professor hinted, you need to consider three cases for `v1` and `v2`:

```
if v1 < v2 then ...
else if v1 > v2 then ...
else ...
```

Looking at the first one, `v1 < v2`, we should pick `v1` as the "root".

It's not very difficult to convince yourself that

```
(IfThenElse p T1 E1) bddAnd (IfThenElse q T2 E2)
```

is equivalent to

```
IfThenElse p (T1 bddAnd (IfThenElse q T2 E2)) (E1 bddAnd (IfThenElse q T2 E2))
```

that is, you create one "tree" from two by recursing into both branches of the `IfThenElse` you chose, bringing the other tree along.
The recursion will terminate since `bddAnd` is applied to smaller and smaller arguments, and the result will be ordered as long as the input was ordered (which I assume we are allowed to assume).

Matching the code above,

```
 | bddAnd (left as (IfThenElse (v1, t1, e1))) (right as (IfThenElse (v2, t2, e2))) = 
        if v1 < v2 then IfThenElse (v1, t1 bddAnd right, e1 bddAnd right)
        else ...
```

(Using `as`-patterns to make it easier to refer to the parameters as wholes.)

The remaining two cases left as an exercise.

Comment: This definition for 'ordered' is in accordance with the one for [OBDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram)s.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `as` instead of `@` for as-patterns.

Comment: @SimonShine It's a good day when you get to learn something :-)

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan I always get that wrong. It's probably not correct now either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you explained this really nicely! Am I correct in my understanding of how the other cases work? (in the edited part of my question)

Comment: @AndrewBrooke The equal case isn't quite correct – since the proposition letter is the same, you'll choose the same branch from both if-then-else's regardless of its truth, and you only need the respective "then" and "else" parts for the recursion, not the entire trees. (I hope that made some kind of sense.)

Comment: Ah whoops `true1` should be `then1`. Like this? `IfThenElse (prop1, then1 bddAnd then2, else1 bddAnd else2);` Or am I still misunderstanding?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke That looks correct to me. (Disclaimer: I haven't tested any of this, and I may be completely wrong.)

Comment: Thanks, in the few test cases I've worked through it seems to be producing the right answer